# Infinite loop in React button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This simple React button class triggers an infinite loop on click (i.e. logging 'click!' to the console 100s of times):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TestButton.js

exports.TestButton = React.createClass({

    onClick: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Click!')
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>Click me!</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.js

var TestButton = require('./TestButton.js').TestButton;

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <TestButton/>
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

The infinite loop is not triggered every time, but around every 10th time I load the page and click the button (in a non-repeatable manner). It's independent of the browser I use.

Any ideas where this is coming from?

I know this isn't repeatable in a JS-fiddle. The question is 'Where should I start to look in my setup for where this condition is coming from? Browserify? Imported scripts? React itself?'

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and couldn't reproduce at all. Here's the test code: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/YyYRVx?editors=001

Comment: Thanks! As I said, I can't reliably reproduce it either, but it does pop up every few times I load my page.

Comment: Does it occur right away or only once you click? Could you be invoking the function in you `onClick` attr instead of assigning it? Also, what else does your `onClick` function do in your actual source? I'd start looking for a bug in the React code before thinking it could be something with the setup FWIW

Comment: @ChrisHawkes: No console errors.

Comment: @Mat: It occurs only when I click. I use the code as shown, so I'm sure I assign the function, not invoke it, right? The onClick function doesn't do anything else, I narrowed down the problem to the function in the example and it still persists.

Comment: Yep, it's assigning it not invoking in your example. Is your code for work or somehow covered by an NDA? It would be nice to see exactly what you're doing if the example you posted doesn't replicate the issue in jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe unrelated but still relevant, since the element is a `button` and not an `a` you don't need all the prevent default stuff, no need to pass the `event` param

Comment: @Mat: We have a misunderstanding: the code I use on my local machine that triggers the 'mystery infinity loop' is exactly the one above. I call it 'mystery' because it doesn't happen every time, only every ~10th time I click this button, suggesting some kind of race condition (?). My assumption is that whatever triggers this is special to my machine/setup/whatever, and that's the reason you cannot replicate it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand. That is strange. Is your code hosted on github by any chance?

Comment: If not, one strategy you could try is.. recreate your project in a generic way, including all setup, and try to replicate it. If your current project is proprietary you can then host the generic version publicly for feedback from the community. If it doesn't replicate it then it helps you narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if it'll help as your code part doesn't has any parameter but I had almost the same symptoms, the onclick callback function was called in a loop:

```
<Button onClick={this.close(id)}>
    Close
</Button>
```

I finally understood my mistake. A closure was expected while I was simply running the function... So, if the function doesn't take any parameter, we can just use `onClick={this.close}` but otherwise, in ES6, we need to use arrow functions to simply pass the function:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.close(id)}>
    Close
</Button>
```

`onClick` the anonymous function is called and executes `this.close(id)`