# How to pass a field of datasource as parameter of onclick function in a table row using ant and ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, antd, tablerow

I'm using ant and ReactJs to work on a project and encounter a problem as follows: my datasource is an array of objects that contain some fields like id, photoUrl, name, phone and email. I use this datasource to create a table which has columns avatar, name, phone number, email, and action. Action is a link text edit and also has an onClick function, which is used to edit the information of a table row.

Now i want to pass the id of the data in each row to the parameter of the edit onClick function. What I have tried so far is set the dataIndex of column Action to "id" and pass the id as a parameter to the onClick function like the code below, but it just hang up the screen.

[image]

```html
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  key: 'id',
  render: (id) => (
    <span>
      <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.handleEditBtnClick(id)}>
        Edit
      </a>
    </span>
  ),
},
```

This is an example of my data object

```html
{
    "id": 21,
    "photoUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/d11b1b/ffffff&text=patient+21",
    "displayName": "patient 21",
    "phone": "0901993159",
    "email": "pp21@yopmail.com"
},
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are binding the handleEditBtnClick function to you onClick is wrong

**It should be: `onClick={() => {this.handleEditBtnClick(id)}}`**

The current implementation is trigerring the handleEditBtnClick function call on each render instead of binding the function with onClick. And you the render goes into infinite loop and your screen hangs.

```
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  key: 'id',
  render: (id) => (
    <span>
      <a href="javascript:;" onClick={() => {this.handleEditBtnClick(id)}}>
        Edit
      </a>
    </span>
  ),
},
```

You can also refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522344/6487887) which further explains this problem

Hope it helps. Revert for any confusions.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.handleEditBtnClick(id)}>
            Edit
          </a>
```

To:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick={() => this.handleEditBtnClick(id)}>
            Edit
          </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to edit the row you can also manage it with state like this:

```
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  key: 'id',
  render: (id) => (
    <span>
      <a href="javascript:;" onClick={() => {this.setState({selected: id})}}>
        Edit
      </a>
    </span>
  ),
},
```